# Running Total based upon a Running Total

Tags: crystal-reports

My Crystal Report is grouped by `{table.employee}`. I created a running total to get the employee's resignation date if applicable, `{table.hr_status_date}` - The running total for resignation date evaluates based on the following formula, then reset for every different employee:

```
{table.hr_status} = ["Resign", "Terminated", "Laid Off", "Retired"]
```

Now I'd like to put  the name of the primary location `{table.primary_location}` where the employees worked on their resignation date. I'd need to put this information the group footer. The field, `{table.primary_location}` is in the same table as the field, `{table.hr_status}`. 
I cannot just use the most recent location because an employee could have been rehired since they were resigned, and the location may differ.

How do I get the primary location into the group footer?

Comment: Your title is confusing. Do you want the location that corresponds with the max(date) where the hr_status is in (resign, terminated, laid off, or retired)? Have you tried concatening location and status together?

Comment: Yup! That is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. I usually do this in SQL before bringing it in. Could you perhaps provide some sample data? Read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure. What do you mean by sample data? I provided the running total evaluation. Anything else you want?

Comment: Fake employee data with the fields you are trying to manipulate and show in crystal